# propriedade box-shadow css

Tags: css

boa noite, criei um css para validar meu textbox e coloquei a propriedade

```
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
```

Quando eu rodo a aplicação o estilo não é aplicado no textbox e no código css fica dando a seguinte mensagem:

Validation CSS3.0: rgba(0, 0, 0, .075)  is not a valida value for the box-shadow property.

Seria isso o erro?

Codigo CSS:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
       -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

Comment: tem como você disponibilizar todo o seu código? Eu testei essa linha com os mesmos valores e não deu nenhum erro, funcionou normalmente.

Comment: esse é o codigo que estou usando no CSS. o Meu textbox não pega o estilo, fica o estilo padrão

Comment: Funciona para mim... https://jsfiddle.net/tewo2vw7/ Qual é o browseer que estás a usar? (repara que no exemplo mudei a opacity de `.075` para `.75` pois o primeiro valor não dava para reparar, e usei vermelho.)

Comment: poisé não se o que houve, pra mim nao funciona, postei uma imagem de como ficou meu textbox no link: http://pt-br.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=m8dwjl&s=9 como pode ver o efeito não é aplicado.

Comment: patrão a questão é que o resultado depende do html e do css, seria necessário ter acesso a mais informações para verificar onde pode estar ocorrendo o erro, pode ser o css, o html, o navegador... coloque o bloco do html e do css referente para ver se o erro aparece....

Answer (score 0):

Cara, a opacidade do box-shadow deve ser declarada diferente.

```
.form-control {
  ...
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  ...
}
```

ou como o sérgio colocou acima no https://jsfiddle.net/tewo2vw7/

```
.form-control {
  ...
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  ...
}
```

olha este exemplo no https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

Declaração em opacity:

```
.sua_classe{ 
  opacity: 0.5; /* Browsers Modernos */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);  /* IE 5-7 */
}
```